# Capture packet with DPDK

Tags: capture, packet, dpdk

I use dpdk to capture packet:

```
$RTE_TARGET/app/testpmd -c '0xf' -n 4 --vdev 'eth_pcap0,rx_iface=eth0,tx_pcap=/path/to/file_tx.pcap' -- --port-topology=chained
```

eth0: using kernel driver.
I don't known stream of packet.

```
NICs--->Linux kernel---> Application
```

or

```
NICs--->DPDK library---> Application
```

Answer (score 1):

The flow is a combination of your two options:

```
NIC --> Kernel --> DPDK Library (via the pcap PMD) --> Application (testpmd)
```

Comment: if i using tcpdump to capture packet, then how is it.